# jquery clone combo box not able to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, git, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following table where when I press the first button I call a jquery to clone the first row and add a new row.

```
<table id='vehReg' class='table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable'  style='font-size:10px;table-layout: fixed;'>
                                     <thead>
                                         <tr>
                                              <th style='width: 10%;'>No.</th>
                                              <th style='width: 30%;'>Sel</th>
                                              <th style='width: 20%;'>Desc.</th>

                                              <th style='width: 18%;'><input type= 'button' value='Add Row'  id='addRow()' />
                                  <input type='hidden' value='0' id='totalRows' name='totalRows' /></th>
                                          </tr>
                                      </thead>
                                      <tbody>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            1
                                        </td>
                                            <td>
                                                        <select class='sSelect' data-rel='chosen' style='font-size:10px;max-width:80%;'>
                                              </select> 

                                                <br\><p style='color:#FF0000;' type='text' class='srror' ></p>
                                            </td>
                                           <td>
                                                <input  style='font-size:10px;max-width:80%;' class='descInput' type='text' id='desc' name='desc' ><p style='color:#FF0000;' type='text' class='descError' ></p>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                            </td>
                                          </tr>
                                      </tbody>
```

Below is my jquery for cloning. It clones well the issue now is that once it clone my select is not able to work any more. I just cant select the combo box. Any tweak is needed I am using the bootstrap type of combo box with data-rel to give the option to search within it.

```
    $("#addRow").click(function(){

            var count = $("#vehReg tr").length;
            var $clone = $("#vehReg tbody tr:first").clone();
        $clone.attr({
            id: "emlRow_" + count,
            name: "emlRow_" + count,
            style: "" // remove "display:none"
        });
        $clone.find("input,select").each(function(){
            $(this).attr({
                id: $(this).attr("id") + count,
                name: $(this).attr("name") + count
            });
        });

        $("#vehReg tbody").append($clone);
});
```

Comment: do you have any link to show which bootstrap combo box you are using?

Comment: are you using any plugin for the combo box

Comment: _once it clone my select is not able to work any more_ => not very clear as to what that means. Create a fiddle that replicates the issue.

Comment: there is nothing inside the select..  how is it populated

Comment: I dont a link cause we are on a private ip not public accessible.

Comment: Hi Arun no the population is done using another combo box script when it change then here is this combo box is field which I omit to show to make things more complex

Comment: It is able to clone all the combo box value as I can see if I select one then that one is select in the clone but then I cant fiddle with the combo box any more no search or to choose other option

Comment: If I dont use the data-rel then using normal javascript I am able to clone it and make it work the issue is the data-rel option I had to swap to jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code in my machine and it worked perfectly. Perhaps your problem lies with the bootstrap combo box. So try refresh or reset the bootstrap combo box.

I have used a similar [plugin](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) and had a similar problem. So I used this and it solved my problem.

```
$("#select").selectpicker('refresh');
```

Also i found a small error in your above pasted code.

```
<input type= 'button' value='Add Row' id='addRow' />
```

instead it was like

```
id='addRow()'
```

So here is the updated code with chosen plugin.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#addRow").click(function(){
            var row = "<tr>"+
                    "<td></td>"+
                    "<td><select class='chosen-select'> <option>1 --</option> <option>2 --</option> <option>3 --</option> <option>4 --</option> <option>5 --</option> <option>6 --</option> <option>7 --</option> <option>8 --</option> </select></td>"+
                    "<td><input  style='font-size:10px;max-width:80%;' class='descInput' type='text' id='desc' name='desc' ></td>"+
                    "</tr>";
            $("#vehReg tbody").append(row);
            $(".chosen-select").chosen();
        });
    });
</script>
<body>
    <table id='vehReg'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No.</th> <th>Sel</th> <th>Desc.</th>
                <th ><input type= 'button' value='Add Row' id='addRow' />
                    <input type='hidden' value='0' id='totalRows' name='totalRows' /></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
</body>
```

Hope this helps.

I added the code inside the javascript itself instead of the clone function. In this way it will be easier for you to maintain the count and keep adding the naming conventions to your fields.

Comment: Where to put $("#select").selectpicker('refresh');  I mean which location in my jqeury ?

Comment: I did a further reading the issue is the chosen is not working on clone rows

Comment: what is the plugin that you use ? can you give a link to the plugin

Comment: I read further on google and found that the chosen is the issue. How to reable chose on my clone row?

Comment: Ok I am also trying on my own I think it got to do with changing the way chosen is reapplied

Comment: I dont mind using this method but my select values I get initially from select statement. Can I reuse the previous select value else I got keep doing a new database select each time I clone the row

Comment: you can assign the values as a JSON string inside javascript  and create the select by looping through the values before adding.

Comment: I am not too sure on the json thing can you give me some hint. Back to my earlier codes rite I tried this $(".sSelect").chosen(); why it does not still work ? Must i change my class to chosen-select then only it works is it ?

Comment: I notice if I dont put the class name chosen-select it does not work. Is it a must for that to work ?

Comment: NO. Your code clone the first <tr> , which is already changed to the {chosen}. But what I did is make the select via code itself and then convert it to {chosen}. JSON can be very helpful in cases like this, just give it a try!

Comment: I dont get your when you said clone the first which is already changed to the {chosen}.?

Comment: Ok about the json I solved ready what I do I keep the original value when I did a ajax into a global variable then use back on this addRow call. Now my next challenge can I change the chosen-select class name to my other name ?

Comment: Run your code; Inspect element on the combobox, you will notice the difference; Now click the add button. I dont know a better way to explain, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your help I manage. Is it ok to save the ajax value into a global variable and reuse it later? Is it safe?

Comment: I use it most of the times usually for select options, so I think there is no harm in that. I honestly don't know much about its safety.

Answer (score 0):

Got it problem is in when you are declaring input use id as addRow not addRow().

```
 <input type='button' value='Add Row' id='addRow' />
```

Comment: I have tried same code in my local and it is working fine after changes.

Comment: I have rectified on that but I know the issue is now the problem is chosen is not working.