# How to clone a row of inputs with the parent element's function together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small table with two rows. In the first row I have 5 columns. First is select box displaying group names. WHen any of it selected, the second select box with list of item matching the value of selected group would appear in the next column. In third column, I have textbox for price. Followed by textbox for quantity in another.When price and quantity added the total of this will appear in the last column. In the second row I have a submit button with submits the form upon click.ALl these work perfectly fine.

Now I intend to allow users to dynamically add more of the first row so that they can submit multiple items! For that I'll need to add one more button type of input beside the submit.WHen clicked, it should clone the first row of 5 columns and also the function.

I tried:

```
$("#more_items").on("click",function

{
 $("#clone_this").clone(true,true).appendTo("#submit_item");
});
```

This does clone the row. The first select box when selected from cloned item, the changes happen not to the current cloned row but to the parent row.Also, I couldn't clone more than once!ALso I tried replacing ID with class as I read clone would duplicate the ID yet no avail.

Now, how do I clone with the jquery also working correctly? DO I need to change my script in a way?

Below is my script for reference.
FORM

```
<form action="#" method="POST" id="submit_item">
<input type="text" name="contract_id" value="" id="contract_id2"/>
<table>
    <tr><th>Group Item</th><th>Nama Item</th><th>Harga</th><th>Kuantiti</th><th>Amount</th></tr>
    <tr id="clone_this">
        <td>
         <select name='group' style="width:80px;" id="gr">
         <option>Choose group</option>
            <?php
    $group = $agency->show_all_group();
    foreach($group as $k=>$v){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $v['group_id']?>"><?php echo $v['group_name']?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
         </select>
        </td>
        <td id="sub_item">
         <select name='item' style="width:100px;" id="it_id">

         </select>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text"  name="harga" value="" id="harga"/></td>
           <td>
             <input type='text' size='2' value="" name='qty' id='qty'/>
         </td>
              <td><input type="text"  name="amount" id="amount" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next" id="item_s"/></td>
    <td><input type="button"  value="Add more items" id="more_items"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

SCRIPT

```
<script>
var harga;
var qty;
$("#harga").on("keyup",function()
{
    console.log($(this).val());
     harga = $(this).val();
});

$("#qty").on("keyup",function()
{
    console.log($(this).val());
     qty = $(this).val();
     var amount = harga * qty;
    $("#amount").val(amount);
});

 $(document).ready( function ()
 {
    $("#sub_item").hide();
    $('#gr').change(function()
    {

        var gr_id = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
        console.log(gr_id);
        var agency_id = '<?php echo $_SESSION['agency_id'];?>';
        /*show branch for selected department starts*/
        var data;
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: s_path+"get-item.php?group="+gr_id+"&agency="+agency_id, //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#sub_item").show();
            $("#it_id").empty();
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
            {
                $("#it_id").append("<option value='"+data[i].item_id+"'>"+data[i].item_name+"</option>");
            }
            if(data.length == "")
            {
                $("#it_id").append("<option>No items found</option>");
            }

            console.log(data);
        }});//end success

        /*show branch ends*/
    });
});

$(function()
{
    $("#hide1").hide();
    $("#hide2").hide();
    $("#hide3").hide();
    $('#faktor').change(function()
    {

        var val =$(this).val();
        //alert($(this).val());
        if($.trim(val)==1)
        {
            $("#hide1").show();
        }else
        {
            $("#hide1").hide();
        }
    });
    $('#insurance').change(function()
    {
        $("#hide2").show();
        var val =$(this).val();
        //alert($(this).val());
        if($.trim(val)==1)
        {
            $("#hide2").show();
        }else
        {
            $("#hide2").hide();
        }
    });
    $('#bon').change(function()
    {
        $("#hide3").show();
        var val =$(this).val();
        //alert($(this).val());
        if($.trim(val)==1)
        {
            $("#hide3").show();
        }else
        {
            $("#hide3").hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32735852/jquery-clone-combo-box-not-able-to-function/32736364#32736364.  refer the link above to get a clarity on hoe to clone a row. Make your jQuery function `$('#gr').change(function(){});` to `function getSubCat(e){}` and the problem can be solved

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your event to your parent element by using the function with  delegation property. e.g. ".on()" function.

For example:

```
$("table.test").on("click","tr",function(){
//do something
});
```

For all newly created tr element inside the table element with class name ="test" could trigger "click" event due to event delegation. It means after you have clone a new row, your new row could trigger the same event without handling explicitly by yourself

Answer (score 0):

The problem is since you have ids in the elements, when you are cloning you are creating elements with duplicate ids, which is invalid as ID of an element must be unique.

Instead of ID, use class in such cases like

```
<select name='group' style="width:80px;" class="gr">
....
<td class="sub_item">
<select name='item' style="width:100px;" class="it_id">


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit_item .gr').change(function () {

        var $this = $(this),
            $tr = $this.closest('tr'),
            gr_id = $this.find('option:selected').val(),
            $subitem = $tr.find('.sub_item'),
            $it_id = $tr.find('.it_id');

        var agency_id = '<?php echo $_SESSION['agency_id '];?>';

        /*show branch for selected department starts*/
        var data;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: s_path + "get-item.php?group=" + gr_id + "&agency=" + agency_id, //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                $subitem.show();
                $it_id.empty();
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $it_id.append("<option value='" + data[i].item_id + "'>" + data[i].item_name + "</option>");
                }
                if (data.length == "") {
                    $it_id.append("<option>No items found</option>");
                }

                console.log(data);
            }
        }); //end success

        /*show branch ends*/
    });
});
```

Comment: I replaced ids with class and copy pasted your script but cannot clone. WHne I click add more items nothing happens though..why?

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the clone function after copying your script. Now, seems like combo works but returns no item for all selected group..This muts be due to value sent to the php via ajax is wrong. ANyway can you tell me why did you declare variable like this $tr, $this...? Also the price and amount calculation function not working on clone..I used class instead of ID for these yet the same!

Comment: for other elements also you have to make similar changes....